# C Programming: Using Relational Operators - Less than vs less than equals

Tags: c, for-loop, relational-operators

I'm working on a textbook problem and I wrote this piece of code below to identify all prime numbers below a user inputted positive number:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int j, input, notaprime;

    scanf_s("%d", &input);

    printf("List of prime numbers:\n");
    for (; input >= 2; input--)
    {
        notaprime = 0;
        for (j = 2; j < input; j++) //OR (for(j = 2; j*j <= input; j++)
        {
            if ((input % j) == 0)
            {
                notaprime = 1;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                ;
            }
        }

        if (notaprime)
        {
            ;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d\n", input);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When 30 is entered as input, the following is the output:

```
30
List of prime numbers:
29
23
19
17
13
11
7
5
3
2
Press any key to continue . . .
```

However, when I change the relational operator in the inner for loop from:

```
        for (j = 2; j < input; j++)
```

to:

```
        for (j = 2; j <= input; j++) //Changed from less than to less than equals
```

The following becomes the output of input value 30:

```
30
List of prime numbers:
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Now, prime numbers are no longer printing, but I can't think of any logical reason why this is so. My brain hurts now from thinking of possible reasons why this should be valid. Please help. Thanks!

I tried this on codeblocks 16.01 and Visual Studio Community 2015. Output is the same.

Comment: What did you learn at school about thew difference between less.than and equality?

Comment: And you should rework your logic. The part from `if (notaprime)` is unnecessarily complicated. Would you say it like that in natural language? Also use boolean variables for boolean values.

Comment: I like the part `else {;}`. My hint for you will be this, if you started with `j = 1` you would have exactly the same problem, but from the other side. Look at the definition of a prime number.

Comment: if `j == input`, `input % j == 0` is true.

Comment: `j*j <= input` will be fine, but `j <= input` cannot be because each and every number divide itself. So at least iteration you fall in the `notaprime =1` case!

Comment: This would be an outstanding time for you to learn to use the debugger to step through your code, so you can see exactly what's happening.

Comment: Apologies for bothering you guys, I don't know how I couldn't see this simple error! Thank you for taking the time commenting. I will take your suggestions to heart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### There is Logical Error in your code

We know that a prime number is a number which is divided by 1 or itself

when you do `for (j = 2; j < input; j++)` then you check all number below than `input` which is correct.

But when you do `for (j = 2; j <= input; j++)` you check upto `input`.

Since every number is divided by itself `(input % j) == 0` every time, `notaprime = 1;` statment is true hence  no output is produced

Comment: Wow how could I not see this. I didn't know I was this stupid. Thank you!